# Logged out, but still logged in?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, logout

When I tried to log out by clicking the logout link at the top (*first time for me because I don't really log out of S[OFU] unless I clear my browser's session data*), I got the following message:

> You're a registered user.
>
> You can log in or out at any time
>   using the OpenID you've already
>   associated with your account.

And when I clicked on the parts of the site, it seems that I'm still logged in (*see, i'm creating this question after I logged out and this question would probably appear in the list of the questions I asked*) and my name is still appearing at the top of the page.

Is this by-design or is this a bug?

Comment: By-design                              :)

Comment: Of course if you do actually click that "Log Out" button you're probably still [not done logging out](http://screencast.com/t/n3lEn55J0r)...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Have you clicked the `Logout` button below the message?

[image: run rabbit, run!]

Comment: Oh, crap.

Comment: Hence, it's not intuitive enough.

Comment: Needs moar Paint.

Comment: This is the only site that requires me to click the logout link twice just to logout.

Comment: Yes, random, but I'm in a hurry. Could you add some monsters to it?

Comment: Randell: Are you sure? ;)

Comment: Yes.

Comment: Can you also add people that are pointing finger at it ?

Comment: @Clement H.: Hand of God ;)

Comment: Exactly ! Fear the power of the hand !

Comment: I love you, random :)

Comment: Waffles!

Comment: Cannot upvote any harder.

Comment: the "pew pew" makes this image

Comment: My bank, and several other sites I use all do this confirm logout.  My only comment is the message given here is a bit odd...  I know I'm registered, or I wouldn't be logging out, I know I can log in and out, because I have done so at least once.

Answer (score 6):

If you had a "no-touch", "no-confirm" logout, then you could be forcibly logged out at will by any user who can construct an `<img>` tag. How? I leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Hint: it's important! Almost web security 101!

Comment: No points for you unless you explain yourself.

Comment: Golly, even my non-web-dev brain can see the logic in this! Something like `<img src="http://stackoverflow.com/logout.htm"></img>`?

Comment: Does that work?  Hmm.  Odd.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001171.html