# How can I log out?

Tags: support, logout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Logged out, but still logged in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21667/logged-out-but-still-logged-in)

I already clicked on every "logout" I saw on SO. I also cleared my browser's cookies. When I then visit SO, I *still* get logged in. Why?! How does SO know it's me again? This is really troubling me, because I don't know what other sites do the same thing...

What's going on, and how can I log out?

Comment: Or, maybe I'm too eagerly voting: in case you did follow the instructions [in this image](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21667/logged-out-but-still-logged-in/21668#21668): maybe it's a new issue with [the new global login](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/)?

Comment: (But: I am not having any issue logging out. If I log out of Meta, then I stay logged out, even when meanwhile visiting other SO sites. When clicking login on Meta, I am automatically logged in, and redirected. That redirecting does not seem 100% correct yet, but I do get logged in.)

Comment: @Arjan: Yes, I did read that question first and followed the instructions in the image, but it didn't work. Kevin Montrose has the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Log Out Everywhere" clears your global login credentials.  Mind, the next time you login you'll re-acquire them.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin! (I always assumed the "Log Out Everywhere" button's purpose was to log me out on this computer and on all other computers where I might have forgotten to click log out...)

Comment: @ryyst - it also does that.  It gained the "clear global login" function recently.