# disabling auto-login

Tags: support

Is there a way to disable auto-login?

After I log out, I want the session to be over and completely gone.

However, on a public computer, someone can just log in again without my user name or password.

Is there a way to achieve this using the logout button?

[edited to add the following]
Yes, it affects stackoverflow.com and in fact all the sites that use the same software

Comment: Did you close the browser down after logging out?

Comment: Depends on your browser. You somehow need to clear the HTML5 `localStorage` pit for the http://stackauth.com/ domain.

Comment: If local storage is part of the session, that should be cleared by logging out I would have thought

Comment: I just stopped and restarted the browser as a test.  I was still not prompted for a password when I logged in

Comment: Apart from that it might be fiddly to implement, it's not wanted http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73699/allow-users-to-disable-auto-login - So such fringe features certainly go untested.

Comment: A bit strange, because I logged out from one site and wasn't able to auto-log back in. This was because of the local storage. Maybe it depends on the browser. I'm using Firefox, mainly.

Comment: I wonder about *"log in again **without** my user name or password"* versus _"not prompted for a password **when I logged in**"_ — what exactly did you do? Did you really not type your OpenID URL? (If you actually did type it: are you sure it's not your OpenID provider that keeps you logged in? Which OpenID provider are you using?) What exactly do you see? Like: are you getting a "Welcome back, click here to refresh" banner? Which sites? What browser? Details, please! **And did you [really](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21667/logged-out-but-still-logged-in) log out?**

Comment: @mario, I think [Allow users to disable auto-login](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73699/allow-users-to-disable-auto-login) is about logging in to sites *after logging in to another site*. If all is well, then auto-login is inactive after one has logged out. It might be enabled again after visiting a site from which one has not logged out; I'm not sure. (Like: log in to Stack Overflow, go to Super User, log out from SO, go to Server Fault: no auto-login, if all is well. But one still has the SU cookie then: maybe going to SU and *then* going to SF does re-enable auto-login again?)

Comment: @mario I might be willing to implement and test this. How would I go about finding out about contributions to the engine?

Comment: @user36410: Stackoverflow isn't open source. So you can't really contribute code here. I'm not sure if they would be interested, but if you can provide some doc and Javascript addition to the stackauth thingy, then maybe write *team@stackoverflow.com*

Comment: @mario thanks for the quick response. I suggest the question be closed. It does not seem right for me to answer my own question but if you want to answer the question in a suitable way (like "there is no way to do that"), then I will accept the answer

Comment: Nah, I would rather keep the question opened. Someone from the dev team might stumble over it, and (re)implement the logout feature. It counts as open bug report / feature request this way..